# Google sheet imbeded Google form in modal

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I was able to get this to work when the google form is actually linked to the spreadsheet. How do I go about modifying this to allow me to embed the google form in a spreadsheet it is not linked to.

```
/*
Global
*/
var width = 1000;
var height = 700;

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Freight Submission Form').addItem('Submission Form', 'freight').addToUi();
}

function freight(){

  var hs = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ModalDialog');
  hs.width = width;
  hs.height = height;
  hs.publishedUrl = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID").getFormUrl();https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/*formID*/viewform?usp=sf_link
  var userInterface = hs.evaluate()
  .setWidth(width)
  .setHeight(height);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Form');
}

function getSize(type){
  if(type === 'width')
    return width - 20;
  if(type === 'height')
    return height - 20;
  return 600;
}
```

*Update: I got this working as I wanted on my google account. Basically I perform a call with a button to the function "freight". This opens a modal with the specified form attached to the spreadsheetID I am referencing.

My new issue is that this only works for me as the document owner and I need this to work for any user including anonymous. I have tried publishing it as a web app, but still no dice. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated the original post with where I am and a description

Comment: What do you mean that only work for you? How do you shared your spreadsheet? What happens when an anonymous user access your spreadsheet and try to open the modal dialog?

Comment: When I am logged in as the owner it works. When I log into another google account it asks me for permission to run the script and once permission is granted it works. When I attempt run it anonymously it states "Script freight experienced an error" and never asks for permission to run it.

 So the question is how do get anonymous users able to use it?

Comment: It would appear upon further investigation that anonymous users doesn't mean what i thought. You apparently have to be logged in to access scripts. I guess I will need to chase down how to open this form in a side bar when the document is opened maybe? Sigh...